# Automatically connect all nodes with all the other nodes in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

Assuming I have created a `MultiDiGraph` in `networkx` as follows:

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
for i in range(5):
   G.add_node(i, features=...)
```

So the resulting graph might look like this:

[image]

Is there a way to now connect all nodes with all the other nodes (except self-edges) without specifying each target and source node manually?

I'm aware of the function `nx.complete_graph()` but I wonder whether there's a way to first create the nodes and then assign the connections in an automatic way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
from itertools import product

G.add_edges_from((a,b) for a,b in product(range(5), range(5)) if a != b)
```

drawing

```
pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, arrows=True, node_size=700)
```

[image]